# How to access div tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access nested div tags.  It is much like a two dimensional array.  I was hoping I could access them like one and tried to do this in javascript.  I am making a game of battleship and want to be able to change the color of one slot on the board when a user guesses there.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0].document.getElementsByTagName("div")  
[0].document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.backgroundColor='red'
```

Sadly this doesn't work (not because of error on my part.  It just doesn't work that way).

I was wondering If there was another way similar to this that would let me acess separate nested div tags.

If you are wondering what the div tags look like here is a general representation of them.  I use css to make them into a 10 by 10 board. And I have to boards.  (the reason for article[0])  There are ten div tags nested in one on each line.

```
<article>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>

</article>

<article>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    <div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>

</article>
```

I have a fiddle of it here http://jsfiddle.net/zachooz/hL4Qk/.  Its a bit messy because I made it a bit ago while I was still learning the basics of html so bear with me.

Comment: You might want to consider jQuery, it makes iteration over DOM elements much easier.

Comment: I don't know jQuery yet :/ I'm still learning.

Comment: could you provide to put it in jsfiddle.net? so that you can put your css out there

Comment: Okay I'm making it now!

Comment: Why do you repeat `document` between `getElements...` calls?

Comment: There are ways to return your various divs for manipulation, but what ones are you interested in and why?

Comment: @ llya I was just trying to see if it worked quickly so wasn't paying much attention to that.

Comment: Hi,what exactly are you hoping to accomplish with the divs?  Do you want to make them all a different background color such as red? http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/hL4Qk/1/

Comment: Chris I know I could give each an id but that would be a lot of work.  I'm pretty new and tried doing nth-child but I came across a problem with that.  What I am hoping I can do is access them somewhat like an 2 dimensional array because I'm holding the info for the ships in battleship in a two dimensional array.

Comment: Or perhaps to turn the background color red when a square is clicked on? http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/hL4Qk/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A.S. please include errors from the [javascript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) when posting buggy code.

---

```
document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0].document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

This is wrong on many levels.

`document` is an object which contains all the HTML nodes of the page. `document.getElementsByTagName("article")` returns an array of all of the HTML nodes with the attribute `name` equals to "article".

The logic with which you assume `document` is contained inside of this array is plain wrong: `document.getElementsByTagName.document` has no meaning.

Instead, this is what you want to do.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0]
var array = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < divs.children.length; i++) {

    array[i] = divs.children[i]

}

array[2].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

You now have an array containing all the divs of the first "article" tag.

If you want to combine this with the second "article" tag to create a multidimensional array, you might want to iterate over the 2 arrays and create it by yourself. As far as I know, the DOM does not provide any method to create 2d array out-of-the-box. Doing so by yourself is just a matter of a few for loops.

Comment: not only. You now have to loop over the 2 arrays in order to build your own 2d array. Next time, check the JS console - you'll spot the error much quicker. Check the link in the answer ;)

Comment: Just be aware that this method also returns the row wrapping `div` element in the resulting node list.  Easy to check for by checking how many children it has or by skipping that index.

Comment: I was able to do this document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[3].style.backgroundColor='red'

Comment: But get by name wouldn't work with nested divs :/ document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0].getElementsByTagName("div")[3].getElementsByTagName("div")[3].style.backgroundColor='red';

Comment: that's because you're using [3] also on the second call.

Comment: There are ten inside each div so 3 should work.  I checked which color 3 changed so I know it calls the right one.

Comment: turns out this is a bit complicated - I'm updating the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Nice simple answer saturnix.  One prob though, is there a way to only make one div red not a whole row?

Comment: Of course there is. In the code I've showed you the correct way to access a node childrens: you may use the same scheme used to access childs of "article" to access the childs of "div". array[1].children[1].style.backgroundColor will give you an example.